Should ID questions be closed as duplicates once the OP confirms the answer is in another ID question?
If someone asks an ID question, and it turns out the answer is the same as another ID question already on the site, should we close the new one as a duplicate?
Back in 2018, identification questions were mass-closed, locked, and deleted. Now that ID questions are allowed again, those affected by the 2018 action have been restored. While ID questions previously closed as duplicates were also reopened, the community has begun re-closing them as duplicates. This has sparked debate about whether ID questions should be closed as duplicates simply because they share the same answer.
Here are some examples where these duplicate closures have been disputed:

90's/early 2000's movie - A group trapped in a huge building complex and trying survive traps - Closed unilaterally in 2016 by an identify-this-movie gold tag badge holder.

Meat Trademark: It seems unhelpful as an archive to mark drastically different Q's as dupe just because they lead to the same answer. 1 + 1 should not be a dupe of 3 - 1.
Valorum: @MeatTrademark - Signposts can look very different, but if they lead to the same place, they're duplicates. "London This Way' and "ロンドン・ディス・ウェイ" might look very different, but they mean the same thing.
Meat Trademark: These Q's don't say the same thing, unlike those signs. They are very different things that happen to lead to the same result. It's nice for posterity to have the different clues for those who would seek out the same thing. This Q is about traps and fighting robots and does not mention VR, the other Q doesn't mention traps, robots or the sewers.
Valorum: That's not how SE works. If the questions lead to the same answer, they're considered to be fundamentally the same question, regardless of how they're phrased.


70s movie featuring primitive people visited by advanced beings in a giant stone head with a testing scene reminiscent of A Clockwork Orange - Closed in 2015 by a regular user and an identify-this-movie gold tag badge holder.

Meat Trademark: Very different questions shouldn't be dupes just because they have the same answer, These questions are all different enough. Zardoz is just like that.
Valorum: @MeatTrademark - If we allow clutter, we end up like quora with endless versions of the same question littering the place like garbage. It helps to think of the duplicate process as archiving useful iterations of the same question


Old series about guy scientist and future?

Meat Trademark: Even if the answers are the same, the questions are too different.


Serial killer chases teenage actors - Closed unilaterally in 2015 by an identify-this-movie gold tag badge holder.


On the other hand, here are some ID questions that were recently re-closed as duplicates by the community, seemingly without much debate:

Horror movie about a killer in mental institution, before 2006? -  Closed unilaterally in 2015 by a moderator.
50s movie with character screaming "Can radiation do this?" - Closed unilaterally in 2016 by an identify-this-movie gold tag badge holder.

It appears that between 2015 and 2016, closing ID questions as duplicates if they were already answered was quite common.
For a bit of perspective, our sister site, Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, also allows ID questions. Their general consensus is that if two ID questions have the same answer as confirmed by the OP, one should be closed as a duplicate of the other: Why would VTC as duplicate be appropriate for a story identification question?
Should we follow a similar approach here on Movies & TV SE? Should we close these ID questions as duplicates or is there a good reason to keep them open, even when they share the same answer?

If I should name one single policy on SciFi.SE that we definitely don't want anywhere else for being be a downright insanely perverted misinterpretation of SE, it'd be their handling of duplicates. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson "If I should name one single policy on SciFi.SE that we definitely don't want anywhere else for being be a downright insanely perverted misinterpretation of SE, it'd be their handling of duplicates." Those questions were actually closed as duplicates before the February 2018 ID purge, but the recent restoration of ID questions by the CMs reopened them. Turns out, SF&F SE’s dupe closure policy was also M&TV SE’s policy at the time.

@galacticninja Not really. I haven't taken a look at the specific questions, but that certainly was never an actual policy. Of course nothing prevents an ID question from getting closed as a duplicate, in fact not even the asker does.

@NapoleonWilson "that certainly was never an actual policy" Interesting. I assumed it was site policy since a moderator and a gold tag badge holder were behind those closures. It seems that it was just their personal call to close them.

As is with many a closure ultimately. There's not an actual policy for a ton of things. Closing questions is generally a judgement call if they're not clearly off-topic. Actually, looking at the questions, they do seem to be quite similar indeed. As said, ID questions can very well be closed as duplicates. I mean, you're experiencxed enough to understand that policies rarely ever come down to always-or-never decisions.

@NapoleonWilson Closures can be a judgment call, but when a mod or gold tag badge holder steps in, I usually assume they’re aligning with community consensus or site policy, given their ability to close questions unilaterally. That’s why meta posts like this pop up: when those privileges aren’t used in alignment with the community or policy.

The policy is to close questions as duplicates when they're asking the same question, has always been and has never been contested. When exactly that is the case is left up to the judgement of the users entrusted with these moderation abilities. You still haven't given a single argument why they weren't "in alignment with the community", though, other than saying "well, other questions didn't get closed" (like, yeah, not all ID questions are duplicates, are they?). But are gold tag badge closing powers kind of a bad idea? They never actually were a good idea to begin with. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson "You still haven't given a single argument why they weren't "in alignment with the community"" I’m not arguing that those closures were in alignment with the community consensus. I’m not the one who closed them in the first place; I’m just inferring from the actions of the moderator and gold tag badge holder. Turns out they might not be closing in alignment with the community consensus (if I'm understanding what you're saying correctly).

@NapoleonWilson "They never actually were a good idea to begin with." As for gold tag badge closing powers, I agree they’re not a great idea, especially for meta categorization tags like [[tag:plot-explanation]]. No one can possibly be an expert on every movie or TV show plot, and the same goes for [[tag:character]] and [[tag:analysis]].

I do agree with Valorum's answer that pragmatically it is certainly desirable to guard ourselves against people asking for the same movie over and over again, which in the past did certainly happen for some films. However, that answer also makes a significant point that it later seems to ignore in that what we actually want to guard ourselves against is "the endless re-asking of what amounts to the same question". Now two very different ID questions that just happen to look for the same film aren't actually the same questions.
Of course ID questions are a bit of a special case in the sense that there really isn't much insight to be gained from them other than what the searched movie is. It ultimately doesn't really matter to anyone else (not even others looking for the same film) what specific details the question is looking for nor why the answer is actually correct. That is, however, a shortcoming of ID questions in general. But if we want ID questions as first class citizens on this site, I think we need to treat them like any other SE question. If we want to present them as valuable questions to ask and answer, we need to encourage good questions and answers. And for example a good ID answer actually adresses the specific question and why the film fits to the details.
Yet if we decide that merely looking for the same film disregarding of the actual details makes them duplicates, we pretty much admit that the question and answer themselves ultimately don't matter and that we're merely providing a throwaway service for naming films, which is one interpretation of what SE does but IMHO not the one it ought to strive for nor the one this site set out to be.
The same holds for placing special emphasis on acceptance here. Yes, the primary goal of an ID question is to name the film that the asker looked for. However, acceptance has never been the be-all-end-all of an SE question and again, if we want to posit ID questions as valuable SE questions in their own right, then a good answer is much more than merely one with a green check mark next to it. In the same way as an accepted answer doesn't actually make for a good question, it doesn't make for a good answer either, nor does it make two very different questions duplicates of each other.
This does of course not mean we can't close ID questions as duplicates, on the contrary. We close questions that ask the same question as duplicates all the livelong day and we can very much do that with ID questions if they ask very similar questions, as to be determined on a case by case basis. But you knowing they're looking for the same film does not make those questions the same question nor does the asker reading the film title and thinking it's his film based on information other than the explanations in the answers. In fact we don't even have to wait for the asker's opinion if the questions are sufficiently similar to be duplicates.
If we want to present ID questions as proper questions rather than merely provide a quiz service under the guise of a valuable question archive, we need to treat them as proper SE questions and for that the content of the question and how answers adress that actually matters. So on the bottom line
close them if they ask the same question based on similar remembered details, like we do with any other question, because otherwise their answers would need to concentrate on very different aspects of the film.

98% of this answer seems to be a rambling diatribe against ID questions.

A bit maybe, but 98% is your usual exaggeration, Richard. ;-) If anything, though, what the question is trying to do is make the best of the fact that these questions are here to stay. And if y'all want to pretend they are valuable questions, you gotta treat them like they are. Saying "the movie title is everything that counts" (be that for being a duplicate or assessing the quality of questions and answers), is merely you dropping the mask of ever pretending those to be valuable questions in the first place, rather than the quiz show it is. You want them to be SE questions, treat them so.

"It ultimately doesn't really matter to anyone else (not even others looking for the same film) what specific details the question is looking for nor why the answer is actually correct." I have to disagree with this take—it feels like a pretty cynical view of ID questions, and honestly, it’s part of why they got banned in the first place. Many of our ID questions have tens of thousands of views, which shows that people often share similar memories of the same film or show. So, the specific details in the ID question and its answers can definitely matter to more people than you’d think.

@galacticninja But well, then have them actually matter instead of saying "as long as the film title is correct, it's a good answer and it's the same question as this other totally different one". Treat the question and answer content with the relevance you say it has. (The general "you" of course.)

I’m not sure why we’re revisiting the "shortcoming of ID questions" or the "quiz service" argument. I thought we’d put that debate to rest when we reallowed ID and trivia questions. Whether someone views it as a "quiz service" doesn’t really matter (I personally don’t).

First of all, @galacticninja, this answer isn't arguing to ban ID question yet again, as has been mentioned repeatedly. However, you should also realize that the reallowance of ID questions hasn't suddenly voided any and all shortcomings others see with these questions. Like dude, why you think it is still a controversial issue? You think everyone forgot all their criticism of these questions because of a few upvotes? It very much matters how people view these questions, especially if they want to make them work on this site...

...You may disagree if these questions pose a problem for site quality or what your attitude towards duplicates says about these questions, of course you may and you do. But if your argument is that now that a consensus has been reached, we throw out all considerations for the site and the quality of its posts, then I'm afraid you don't actually know how consensus works at all. Or why all this struggle to bring them back in the first place? Didn't you realize "this debate had been put to rest" 6 years ago, Mr. Ninja? ;-)

If y'all wanna have a reasonable site, you can't really afford to get a heart attack whenever someone says they don't like ID questions or votes one down. Same as we couldn't make a 180 whenever someone was sad they couldn't find their movie now. You can't cleanse people's minds. All you can do is take it and try to convince them of those questions' value. And for that, standing by that value and showing it to others is the best way to convince the detractors that the consensus is a reasonable one. Coming at it like nothing matters anymore now is quite the opposite of that, I'm afraid.

I can see the points in favour and against, but the key is that we need a clean and simple method of preventing clutter and the endless re-asking of what amounts to the same question. We should close one ID question as a duplicate of the other if (and only if) the two posters agree that it's the same film or show.

So why is this even contentious?
The problem is that some users tend to see the duplication process as a form of deletion or censure, whereas in reality it's simply an archiving process. It keeps the valuable bit (the question) so it can be found by search engines, but takes the searcher directly to a single answered question, one that can be curated much more easily. Instead of having ten questions linking to a range of sources, you have one single question that will be viewed ten times as often, and hopefully linking to high quality sources that are less likely to rot
Once you're able to see it as a positive Stack Exchange feature that keeps our little patch of garden neat and tidy, and not a punishment for the asker, the duplication process makes a lot more sense.

When the question is displayed, a banner will be included to provide a link to the target question

and

Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.


As an opponent of closure based solely on answers, I can assure you that thinking duplication to be a "form of deletion or censure" is definitely not the only reason people are opposed to this approach. I see this policy driven to 11 on other sites, where even the mention of a possible answer in a side-note on another question's answers can get a question duplicate-closed and I frankly find that utterly insane. If the questions ultimately ask different questions, it doesn't matter that there could happen to be an answer covering both. As someone else neatly said, 1+1 and 3-1 aren't duplicates.

Of course one also has to agree that identification questions are of such limited value in themselves, that pragmatically it is kind of useful to guard against people asking for the same movie over and over again. But even then the questions could be significantly different, concentrating on very different aspects of the film and in that case the answers should also concentrate on answering these details, rather than just naming a film and calling it a good answer just because it got accepted. Acceptance really doesn't mean all that much on SE anyway.

@NapoleonWilson - Identify-this-x questions are, at their heart, probably the most useful questions on the site because they definitively help someone with a real-world problem.

Then maybe treat them and their answers with the respect they supposedly deserve.

@NapoleonWilson - They deserve to have their questions answered. "Look over here, here's the answer" is a perfectly good answer in 99.99% of cases.

Also, I know it's a terrible idea to harp on with you of all people about the value of identification questions (and the dice are cast anyway). ;-) But this shtick about "solving a real-world problem" really means nothing on a site whose very purpose is to discuss art. Nothing here will ever be "useful" in such a strict definition of "use". At the point where you feel guilty for not feeding the poor instead of pondering on why Dr. Strange didn't travel back in time to kill Thanos as a baby, helping some guy find a YouTube clip he dreamed of isn't going to change much about that. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson - Are there no prisons? Are there no workhouses?
